# How do I change 'asp:LinkButton Text value <span>'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm beginner in asp.net, I'm using below code for `asp:Button`, it's working fine.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadLoction" OnClientClick="this.value = 'Loading....';this.style.backgroundColor = '#DC143C';" runat="server" OnClick="btnLoadLoction_Click" Text="Load" />
```

Here problem with `asp:linkbutton`, I'm trying to change button text to look like below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnLoadLoction" OnClientClick="this.value = 'Loading....'; this.style.backgroundColor = '#DC143C';" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnLoadLoction_Click"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span> Load</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using ASP.NET WebForms? It's been obsolete for about a decade now. You're doing yourself a disservice if you're using WebForms to learn ASP.NET.

Comment: check jquery verison and version of bootstrap. it should work according to code you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that LinkButton is rendered like the < a > html tag and when the client click is fired, you must work with javascript and rendered < a > html element... so the difference is that while a button has its text on value attribute, the < a > element don't, look how it's rendered, you'll see something like

```
<a id="btnLoadLoction" on-click="this.value = 'Loading....';this.style.backgroundColor = '#DC143C';" ><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span> Load</a>
```

So, to change it's content (pay attention to "content" word... we're no more talking about an attribute value), you shall change his innerHTML property.
Try to do something like

this.innerHTML ='Loading...' in your javascript

Comment: @IbneKayesh So, check it as a solution, this could be helpful for other users... btw I'm glad if it has been an helpful support to this problem